# c# Sqlcommand error

Tags: c#, .net

```
foreach (string str in TestWords)
{
  //spam
  SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("select count from keys,files,folders where keys.fileid=files.id and keys.kname='" + str + "' and files.spam=1 and folders.id<>" + FolIter + " and files.folderid<>" + FolIter + " and files.id='" + s[0].ToString + "'", cn);
  int i6 = Convert.ToInt16(cmd6.ExecuteScalar());
  double temp = Convert.ToDouble((i6 + 1) / (i7 + i8));
  //non spam

  **error**

  SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand("select count from keys,files,folders where keys.fileid=files.id and keys.kname='" 
    + str 
    + "' and files.spam=0 and folders.id<>"
    + FolIter
    + " and files.folderid<>" 
    + FolIter 
    + " and files.id='" 
    + s[0].ToString 
    + "'", cn);
  int i9 = Convert.ToInt16(cmd9.ExecuteScalar());
  temp2 = Convert.ToDouble((i9 + 1) / (i7 + i8));
  Sdoc = Convert.ToDouble(Sdoc * temp);
  NsDoc = Convert.ToDouble(NsDoc * temp2);
}
```

The error iam getting is:**Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group'**

Comment: Supplying what line the error is occuring would be helpfull, and the rest of the scope.

Comment: Two things: 1) what is `FolIter`, and 2) (and this one is important): do some reading on SQL Injection (start here, for instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163917.aspx), and the steps to take to avoid it. Your code is wide open for such attacks.

Comment: Slightly better now that its been formated ;).  I can only hope, you have a type-o, and actually have () after ToString .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using method `ToString()` as Property

change   `s[0].ToString`  ->  `s[0].ToString()`

Remember C# does not allow it.

Answer (score 8):

You have to call the method:

```
s[0].ToString()
```

Answer (score 5):

As Nix, Femaref and Azhar mentioned, .ToString() is the typo that triggers the error message.

May I suggest to use parameters instead of string concatenation ? This way:

```
SqlCommand cmd9 = new SqlCommand("select count from keys,files,folders where keys.fileid=files.id and keys.kname=@name and and files.spam=0 and folders.id<>@FolIter and files.folderid<>@FolIter and files.id=@s0", cn);

cmd9.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", str));
cmd9.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FolIter", FolIter));
cmd9.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("s0", s0));
```

By this way, ADO.NET will deal with your variable as is, you wont have to convert them to string to use concatenation, and you wont be exposed to a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) risk.