# updating values

Tags: sql

```
public void ModificaNomeUtente(int slipno , int basicprice , int premium, int totalamountpaid, int weight , int totalamountbasic , int totalamountpremium , int yeildestimates , int farmercode)
        {
            // Creo la stringa di Connessione al DataBase 
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True");

            // Prova 
            try
            {
                // Creo la query che andrà a modificare il nome utente 
                string sqlQuery = "UPDATE cottonpurchse SET slipno = '" + slipno + "' + basic price = '" + basicprice + "' + premium = '" + premium  + "' + totalamountpaid = '" + totalamountpaid + "' + weight = '" + weight + "' + totalamountbasic = '" + totalamountbasic + "' + totalamountpremium = '" + totalamountpremium + "' + yeildestimated = '" + yeildestimates + "' =  WHERE  farmercode  = '" + FarmerCode + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn);
                // Apro la connessione con il DataBase Login.sdf  
                sqlConn.Open();
                // Eseguo l'istruzione sql 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                // Chiudo la connessione con il DataBase Login.sdf 
                sqlConn.Close();
                // Se la query ha avuto esito positivo imposto la variabile result a true 
                result = true;
            }


            // In caso di eccezzione  
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Visualizzo il messaggio con la relativa eccezzione verificatasi 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                // Chiudo la connessione con il DataBase Login.sdf 
                sqlConn.Close();
                // la query ha avuto esito negativo imposto la variabile result a false 
                result = false;
            }

            finally
            {
                // Chiudo la connessione con il DataBase Login.sdf 
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
```

this doesnt work its not updating could it be cause my values are set to null ?

Comment: Do you get an error? if so what is the error?

Comment: Please post an example what `string sqlQuery` contains

Comment: it just doesnt update , in my sql all those are null and when i enter them as null from the textboxes they enter in the database but when i enter with updating values they dont

Comment: string sqlQuery = "UPDATE cottonpurchse SET slipno = '" + slipno + "' + basic price = '" + basicprice + "'

Comment: Change `+` to a `,` `UPDATE cottonpurchse SET slipno = '" + slipno + "' , bacic...` Also, you have a `=  WHERE =` change it to `WHERE =`

Comment: o changed it and put the queston marks instead do u think it has anyhting to do with the fact that they are saved as null in my db?

Comment: No, I used the question marks as examples, replace them with your variables

Comment: it still doesnt work! :(

Comment: fyi i dont know the the values to be entered right now thats y i put them as null in my sql db

Answer (score 1):

That statement parses to something like;

```
UPDATE cottonpurchse 
SET slipno = '???' + basic price = '???' + premium = '???' + totalamountpaid = '???' + weight = '???' + totalamountbasic = '???' + totalamountpremium = '???' + yeildestimated = '???' =  WHERE  farmercode  = '???'
```

There is an `=` before the `WHERE` which is illegal, did you mean `,` instead of + `?`

```
UPDATE cottonpurchse 
SET slipno = '???' , basic price = '???' , premium = '???' , totalamountpaid = '???' , weight = '???' , totalamountbasic = '???' , totalamountpremium = '???' , yeildestimated = '???'  WHERE  farmercode  = '???'
```

Comment: but those values are int is it still ok to have ' ?

Comment: I just put ??? inplace of your variables (which I have no way of knowing) to indicate where they would be inserted

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** everyone's comments are valid.  Your SQL is full of errors: extra spaces, extra +, and extra =.  You are confusing yourself trying to build up a string that way...

That said, your SQL query string should be this:

```
string sqlQuery = "UPDATE cottonpurchse SET slipno=" + slipno + ", basicprice=" + basicprice + ", premium=" + premium  + ", totalamountpaid=" + totalamountpaid + ", weight=" + weight + ", totalamountbasic=" + totalamountbasic + ", totalamountpremium=" + totalamountpremium + ", yeildestimated=" + yeildestimates + " WHERE farmercode=" + FarmerCode;
```

It is confusing becuase you are building a string.  The best (and safest) way to do what you are trying to do is use SQL parameters.  See: [c# Sqlcommand error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658438/c-sqlcommand-error) (specifically the answer that shows "Parameters.Add")

Comment: still doesnt work does it have anything to do with the fact that they are saved as null in my db?